# storing huge HashMap in database

Tags: java, database, hashtable

I have something like:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class A {
    HashMap<Long, List<B>> hashMap = new HashMap<Long, List<B>>();
}

class B{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

And I want to store this in database, because it will be huge huge.

I will have more 250000000 keys in HashMap and each key representing huge list of data (say list size may be around 1000).

How I can do this for best performance on retrieving list of B's objects with Long hashKey from database?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Speed depends on what your indexed column(s) would be.  Would you also be considering indexing on elements of B (a, b, or c)?

Comment: Thank Makoto, obviously I will index on hashkey, because I need to retrieve data based on hashkey.

Comment: What are your choices on database?  This type of key-value storage is probably more suitable for big-table like technology, like mcached or Riak.

Comment: I am thinking to use Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: Is there anything else you can share to put this data in context? Are you processing it randomly or (at least somewhat) sequentially? Are all entries truly random or could there be clusters of related ones?You're looking at 3+Tb data set, unless you're thinking supercomputers your performance will depend mostly on minimizing disk access by ordering related data entries to be close to one another. You hash index could (technically) be held in memory, so you (technically) _could_ skip DB performance overhead... not that you should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a very large data set of up to 1/4 bn * 20 * 1 k or about 5 TB, the main problem you have is that it can't be stored in memory and is too large to store on SSD, so you will have to access disk efficiently otherwise you are looking at a latency of about 8 ms *per key*  This should be your primary concern otherwise it will take days just to access every key randomly once.

Unless you have a good understand of how to implement this with memory mapped files you will need to use a database, preferable one design to handle large numbers of records.  You with also need a disk sub-system not only for capacity but to give you more spindles so you can increase the number of requests you can perform concurrently.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank for calculations.. I may be wrong on calculation. What I am doing is implementing Audio Fingerprint in Java. And I am taking 10 samples/second of original songs. So I will have 600 samples 1 minute play of any song. And I want this for around 50000 songs of around 5-7 minutes of each song.

Comment: ok so you have samples of 50K (songs) * 500 (seconds) * 10 (samples per second) which is 250,000,000 samples in total or if you have 16 bits per sample, about 500 MB.  I am assuming that you need to be able to look up any value very efficiently so you should consider a data structure you can store in Java's memory (on or off the heap)

Comment: You should consider that you will have a low signal to noise ratio meaning you will need to perform a closest match. a hash table can only be used for *exact* matches.

Comment: yes, for exact match I have used fuzz calculations to merge slightly distorted keys to single key in HashMap

Answer (score 2):

To me, this looks like a classical One-To-Many or Many-To-Many association between two tables.

If each B belongs to only one A, then you would have a table A and a table B containing a foreign key to A.

If a given B can belong to multiple As, then you would have a table A, a table B, and a join table between the two tables.

Make sure to index the foreign keys.

Comment: or forget the n-n and just duplicate the tiny As

Comment: Thank JB, I have many Bs to 1 hashKey in HashTable. I will not any B to many hashKey like relation. So in table A, what I will store along with hashKey?

Comment: If there is nothing other than the hash key, then you just need one table for B. I misread the code and thought you had other attributes associated with the hash key.

Comment: Hi JB, but how can I store multiple Bs with one hashKey. I want hashKey as primary key and I will index database for best retrieving performance. I will fectch records based on hashKey only. How can I do this? I am sure we can't store multiple Bs with 1 primary key (hashKey).

Comment: You can store any number of Bs for the same primary key you just can't make it a unique key.  BTW You can't guarantee order in a database unless you add a column to store this. (A list implies you want an ordered collections)

Comment: Hi Peter, No I don't want order in B's list. But how can I make hashKey as primary, because I am going to store multiple B with 1 hashKey, so in table hashKey will repeat for multiple Bs. How can I make it?

Comment: You shouldn't make the hash key the primary key. Use an autogenerated ID as the primary key (using a sequence, for example). A hashKey doesn't uniquely identify a B. The autogenerated ID would have a role similar to the identity of the object in Java.

Answer (score 1):

using [infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/) you could just work with your huge map and have parts of it (the ones not recently accessed) stored to disk to save RAM. easier to do than writing a whole D layer and (i think) faster and uses less memory @runtime (the entire map isnt in memory ever)

Answer (score 0):

You can map this directly as a one to many relationship.  You need two tables.  One to hold the key (let's call it KeyTable), and the other one to keep the B objects (BTable).  On BTable with the B objects, you need a foreign key to the KeyTable.  Then you can query something like this to get the objects with key 1234:

```
  SELECT * FROM BTABLE WHERE key=1234;
```

For performance, you probably should code this using JDBC instead of something like Hibernate, to have better control of memory usage.